# execute() error neovim with substitute command

Tags: vim, neovim

I can't seem to figure out how to set a variable equal to the number of matches in a file.

I have tried this

```
let a=execute('%s/<++>//ne')
```

but it won't work (throws this error:

```
Error detected while processing function myfunctions#Tab:
line    2:
E523: Not allowed here
```

). I want a variable with the number of matches for a regular expression and I can't seem to find a way to use the execute() function with the substitute command. (`execute('%s/test//ne')` throws an error too).

EDIT: I am trying to run this inside a function that is called as an `<expr>` mapping. The full function body is this (control characters properly inserted):

```
function! myfunctions#Tab()
    let a=execute('%s/<++>//ne')
    if a > 0
        return "/<++>^M:noh^Mc4l"
    else
        return "^I"
    endif
endfunction
```

The goal is to insert a tab if the pattern <++> doesn't exist, and if it does, then find it and replace it. I mapped it like this:

```
inoremap <expr> <tab> myfunctions#Tab()
```

Comment: most likely caused by a plugin. try the same if you start vim/nvim with `nvim -u NONE`. (It works on my machine)

Comment: If you look at `:help E523` you'll see it's under the `'secure'` option, which leads me to believe you're trying to execute this operation somewhere where a sandbox is being enforced. Can you [edit] the question and add more context on where you are having trouble with this statement?

Comment: I tried `nvim -u NONE` and it didn't work. @DoktorOSwaldo
EDIT: I mean it still gave me the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you're hitting this error is that a function called in an `<expr>` mapping is restricted and can't modify the current buffer.

From [`:help :map-expression`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression):

> Be very careful about side effects!  The expression is evaluated while obtaining characters, you may very well make the command dysfunctional.
>
> For this reason the following is blocked:
>
> - Changing the buffer text [`textlock`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#textlock).
> - Editing another buffer.
> - The `:normal` command.
> - Moving the cursor is allowed, but it is restored afterwards.

What is triggering this situation is your `:s` command. Even though you're using the `/n` flag, which does not modify the buffer, the `:s` command generally introduces modification and as such is completely blocked under `textlock`.

---

If what you're trying to do is jump to the next `<++>` on tab, then the best option is to use the `search()` function, which will move your cursor to the next match and return the line number (non-zero) if a match was found.

Since an `<expr>` mapping doesn't preserve cursor movement, you should use a normal mapping instead.

This gets tricky quickly though... It turns out this is one of the hardest mappings to get right...

But the gist of it is: you'll want to escape Insert mode temporarily with `CTRL-\ CTRL-O` and call your function. There, you can do your `search()`. If the search matches, you'll need to call `:stopinsert` to interrupt the temporary escape from Insert mode (essentially making it permanent). Then you can run the `c4l` command, but you need to do so using `feedkeys()`, since it will leave you in Normal mode at the end.

If there's no match and you want a tab character inserted, you can then use `feedkeys()` to insert the tab character.

Putting it all together:

```
function! myfunctions#Tab()
  if search('<++>')
    stopinsert
    call feedkeys('c4l', 'n')
  else
    call feedkeys("\t", 'n')
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <silent> <Tab> <C-\><C-o>:call myfunctions#Tab()<CR>
```

Comment: There's actually a better way to define this mapping using Select mode. I'll post an update later to address that. But hopefully this is helpful already.